# Laravel 5 Redirect Not Working When Called From An External Class

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have a controller for adding a user to the database with methods as below

```
public function store()
{

    $request = request()->all();


    $data = [
        'fname' => $request['first_name'],
        'lname' => $request['last_name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($request['password'])
    ];

    (new AddUserService($this))->execute($data);


}

public function successResponse($message)
{

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Great! ' . $message);
}

public function failResponse($message)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Sorry! ' . $message)->withInput();
}
```

On the AddUserService the execute method and constructor is as below

```
private $caller;

function __construct($caller)
{
    $this->caller = $caller;
}

public function execute(array $data)
{

    try{

        $user = User::create($data);

        $this->caller->successResponse('success');

    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->caller->failResponse('Failed');

    }

}
```

When I var_dump('test') at successResponse() or failResponse() method on the controller it is successful indicating the flow reaches there but the redirect does not work, It remains on the same page.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a return in store().Note: I'd rather add the try{} catch{} statement in store() method. It's not a model's purpose to handle this kind of logic.

Comment: `return (new AddUserService($this))->execute($data);` and set in the `execute` function: `return $this->caller->successResponse('success');`. i hope op get the gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the returns

```
return (new AddUserService($this))->execute($data);
return $this->caller->successResponse('success');
return $this->caller->failResponse('Failed');
```